# file_operations.write behavior when no space is left on device

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am writing a memory mapped character device. I can read and write correctly to the device, but my question is about the write behavior in the following case

- When the count of data to write is much more than the available memory.

What would be the proper behavior in this case? Shall I write as much as I can and return the error in the next write? or fail from the beginning since the data is much more than the device capacity?

And to make the question more specific, let's take a FS on a hard-disk (ext3) for example.. what will happen if I tried to write data that is more than the available space on the hard-disk? will it fail before it start? or write as much data it can and fail in the next write?

Comment: ask the client what to do. However, some possibilies: it may be useful to ask the user if the want to  access the the data from somewhere, in the 'cloud', of their choosing. Or provide a web link to where they can download the information later.

Comment: Which real FS and what they do when it gets confused? Some cleanup, some don't. You always leave valid data. And a clue it may be incomplete. Anything else is 'less than helpful' to all who follow. do not rely on the o/s to do something 'sensible'. You may have to do some specific o/s file capability checks. –  Ryan Vincent 1 min ago   edit

Comment: Since it's a character device, the driver should write as much as it can, and then return the number of bytes written.  This is clearly spelled out in the Linux **man** page for `write(2)`.  It is up to the application program to properly detect that a "short" write has occurred.  Your question is essentially asking for permission to introduce a new, undefined behavior to an existing system call.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much depends upon your application. Can your application live with writing partial data ? Is partial data any good ?

IMO, you should do a available memory check before writing anything and return with an error message if you don't have enough memory since otherwise you won't be able to do any meaningful error recovery (if at all you are taking care of it).

Comment: I got your point, and It's something I will consider in an actual application.
But let's assume I want to simulate a real FS for now. what will happen if I try to write more data than the available disk space on a hard-disk with an ext3 FS as an example?

I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: It will copy until there's no more space left.

Comment: *"This pretty much depends upon your application"*  -- Why does that override the Linux **man** page for `write(2)`: *"The number of bytes written may be less than 'count' **if, for example, there is insufficient space** on the underlying physical medium"*?